# re-transmit octet-stream from external api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Ive been trying to retransmit the data received as octet-stream from an external api in my own nodejs application. But I'm having issues implementing this, namely. I know that my approaches have been wrong so far, I have tried converting the api response into a buffer and then sending that buffer as `res.write(buffer(apiResponse.data))`. Really don't know what to do, and searches have been futile so far.

```
const downloadCertificate = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const { headers, data } = await axiosInstance.get(`/certificates/${req.params.txId}`);
  const buf = Buffer.from(data);
  res.set({
    'content-type': headers['content-type'],
    'content-disposition': headers['content-disposition'],
    'accept-ranges': headers['accept-ranges'],
    'content-length': headers['content-length'],
  });
  res.send(buf);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to this problem. first of all the data from the axios response should be returned as a stream. afterwards you can just write data and set headers as equal to the axios headers, hope it makes sense.

```
axiosInstance.defaults.responseType = 'stream';
const { headers, data: stream } = await axiosInstance.get(`/certificates/${req.params.txId}`);
res.set({
  'Content-type': headers['content-type'],
  'Conent-length': headers['content-length'],
  'Content-disposition': headers['content-disposition'],
});
stream.on('data', (data) => {
  res.write(data);
});
stream.on('end', () => {
  res.end();
});
```